# Order of multiple columns in index by value diversity

Tags: database-design, indexing

**The example:**

Table A  has the fields Person and DateTime. I'd like to query the data of a person after a date time. There are 10million rows, there are 1000 different persons and the DateTimes are equally distributed over the period of a year.

**The question:**

When playing a little with a similar situation to the example, i came to following conclusion after taking measures and watching execution plans on a sybase sql database. I couldn't really find good information about in the internet. Would you consider following statement as a general true rule, or does it depend..., and on what?

When there are different columns which have more or less diverse values, and we read data with a statement that uses all columns (with sense) in the index, then it is the best for read performance:

- If an index has one field, then choose the column which has the most diverse values.
- If an index has multiple fields, then choose the columns in the order from the least diverse to the most diverse.

When I imagine an index organising the pointers in a tree, where each node has two descendants, then the above statement seems logical to me, not? I would be as well interested in links about how an index structure is built, used or knowledge about what engines use which types since i feel that has an influence on the statement above...or not? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(While I'm not familiar with Sybase, I think I can contribute few general statements about indexing...)*

> Table A has the fields Person and DateTime. I'd like to query the data of a person after a date time. There are 10million rows, there are 1000 different persons and the DateTimes are equally distributed over the period of a year.

Look like you just need an index with the date/time at its leading edge.

> If an index has one field, then choose the column which has the most diverse values.

If you can choose, then you don't have to pick just one column - pick multiple columns **if** appropriate. For example, a composite index can satisfy AND condition, but separate indexes would be needed for OR.

> If an index has multiple fields, then choose the columns in the order from the least diverse to the most diverse.

The order of fields in the composite index should be primarily influenced by the kind of queries that index is supposed to serve. For example, if both of these queries need to be served:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE C1 = 'foo' AND C2 = 'bar'
SELECT * FROM T WHERE C1 = 'foo'
```

...then it is much better to create just one index on {C1, C2} than two indexes on {C2, C1} and {C1}, even if C2 has better selectivity<sup>1</sup>.

The conventional wisdom states that columns with better selectivity should come first in the composite index, but this rule should not be followed blindly. For example, Oracle can compress the index leading edge, in which case the column with *lesser* selectivity should actually come first. Even without index compression, you might want to [cluster](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) the data on a less-selective column, if that conforms better to your querying patterns.

Indexing is a complex balancing act and I warmly recommend reading [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) for more thorough treatment of the topic...

---

*<sup>1</sup> The ratio between the number of distinct key values in the index and the number of indexed rows. I suppose that's what you mean by "diversity".*

Comment: Thank you for answering it depends. I knew the "conventional wisdom." I started to rethink and swim, when my tests in this specific case showed up, that the index with the less selective column first (couldn't remember that word) was performing around 80times faster. Thats why i got more interested in the internal structure and or different index "types/structures". The clustered index i'll use. Do you have other hints or reasons why a less selective column first could be better? The oracle example targets balancing index size and access fast, no?

Comment: By the way ;) about using single column index for OR queries. One query can just use one index. If the or is really necessary i faced situations where its better to use UNIONS and different queries using AND terms only. I believe you are aware of that, but the above sentence is not expressing well.

Comment: @DiegoFrehner I doubt you got 80x difference just from the selectivity alone. The order of columns probably actually mattered in that particular case. The Oracle example targets index size (and therefore caching and therefore speed).

Comment: @DiegoFrehner As for OR: consider `SELECT * FROM T WHERE C1 = 'foo' OR C2 = 'bar'` - you'll need separate indexes on {C1} and {C2} (not composite index on {C1, C2}) for optimal execution. UNION is just another way to express the same query and any DBMS worth its salt will produce the same execution plan for queries that mean the same thing, even if they are syntactically different.

Comment: I didn't mean to use a composite index. But two queries enabling each to use it's specific single column index and union the result. I agree the dbms should produce the best plan itself and either using just one index or none and filter the second term in full table scan, or produce the union itself if it correctly assumes it's worth. The 80x difference 0.25s to 0.003s seems heavy, but it's what the execution paln analyzer told me. Depending on the chosen filter date as well it used or did not use any index.